# Extracting data from InterpolatingFunction 2D surface plot

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, finite-element-method, precision-and-accuracy

I would like to directly extract the surface plot data from the solution to a differential equation (using NDSolve). While there are many examples of this I haven't been able to find an example in 2D.

Here I am solving a 1D diffusive heat equation and plotting the results (the solution is very poorly behaved with significant artifacts). I would like to be able to extract the heat distributions along the x axis (i.e. the temperature distribution in the rod) for each moment in time and save to something like a text file(s) so I can have direct access to the simulation data and analyze it using a different program. This is easiest done with InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy but I am not sure how to extract and package it.

If anyone has suggestions for improving the accuracy of the solution I would also appreciate it. (I know I can decrease MaxCellMeasure but it greatly increases computation time).

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
parameters = {v -> -1, DT -> 0.000000143, rho -> 1000, c -> 4200, 
eta -> 0.001002};
HEATIMP = (-D[u[r, t], t] - 
 v D[u[r, t], r] + (DT/r^2) D[r^2. D[u[r, t], r], 
   r] + (12. eta)/(rho c) (v/r) (v/r)) /. parameters;
BCE1 = DirichletCondition[u[r, t] == 1, r == 2];
BCE2 = DirichletCondition[u[r, t] == 0, r == 1];
BCTot = {BCE1, BCE2};
ic = {u[r, 0] == 0};
heatdist = 
NDSolve[{HEATIMP == 0, BCTot, ic}, u, {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0.00000, 1}, 
Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005}}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[First[u[r, t] /. %]], {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0.00000, 1}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 20,  
PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {RodPosition, Time, Temperature}]
```

[image: Very Poor Solution]

Comment: You are not solving a 1D diffusion equation but a 2D convection diffusion equation. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decreasing the `MaxCellMeasure` to $5\times10^{-5}$ improves the quality of the solution considerably while still taking only a few seconds to calculate, so I would suggest that as a viable compromise:

```
heatdist = 
  NDSolve[{HEATIMP == 0, BCTot, ic}, u, {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0.00000, 1}, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 5*^-5}}
  ];

Plot3D[
  Evaluate[u[r, t] /. First@heatdist], {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0.00000, 1},
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {RodPosition, Time, Temperature}
]
```

[image: plot of improved solution]

Note that I've removed `MaxRecursion -> 6` and `WorkingPrecision -> 20` from your plotting code because the problems were with the solution from `NDSolve`; more recursion or precision in plotting could not improve the solution, but would only slow the plot down.

---

Rather than digging within the structure of the interpolating function, would it be acceptable to simply evaluate the solution from `NDSolve` at a range of times, and for each time at a range of positions across the rod (i.e. along the rod's profile)?

Something like this (using your definitions):

```
u[r, t] /. First@heatdist;
data = Table[{r, t, u[r, t] /. First@heatdist}, {t, 0.00000, 1, 0.05}, {r, 1, 2, 0.01}];
```

As defined above, `data` contains 21 lists, each of 101 triplets; each triplet is structured as {position along the rod, time, temperature}. Each of the 21 lists corresponds to a point in time; each of the 101 triplets corresponds to a position along the rod.

As a sample of what `data` would contain, here are a series of temperature profiles across the rod over time:

```
ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All] & /@ data[[All, All, {1, 3}]]
```

[image: several temperature profiles at different times]

You could then export `data` to a file, or modify the `Table` to generate appropriate subsets of interest and then export each one, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I still have several questions comments. I put MaxRecursion -> 6 in there because for other solutions I was getting jagged edges and other artifacts and doing this improved the solution (albeit at a significant performance penalty). I had changed MaxCellMeasure but even with smaller cells there are still rather noticeable issues with numerical accuracy (specifically the overshoot above a value of 1).
Last question: How would I go about exporting only the height values (third element) of the table?

Comment: @Iamtired 1) `MaxRecursion` allows `Plot` to more faithfully reproduce any fine structure that is present in the function being plotted, but does not "smooth" the function in any way; that has to be done in `NDSolve`, practically most easily by reducing the size of the FEM cells. 2) Regarding the overshoot above a value of 1, that is a rather small artifact, but again you would want to look into the suggestions provided by NDSolve in relation with the `NDSolve::femcscd` warning that you get.

Comment: @Iamtired  3) To export only the temperature, modify the table to include only that? E.g. `data = Table[u[r, t] /. First@heatdist}, {t, 0.00000, 1, 0.05}, {r, 1, 2, 0.01}]`? and then use `Export` appropriately. This depends on how you want your data exported, e.g. do you want one file per time step?

Comment: I would like for each row in the file to correspond to each plotted temperature distribution. 
For the plots, it would look something like this (plots resemble a step function)
0  0  ... 0  0  1 //
0  0  ... 0  1  1 //
0  0  ... 1  1  1 //
as the system warms up.
I would guess this involves using "Flatten" somehow to remove the innermost bracer and then plotting each list of numbers as its own row.

Comment: @Iamtired With the definitions above, `Export["yourfilename.txt", Chop@data[[All, All, 3]], "Table"]` should give what you want, if I understood your requirements. The `"Table"` format will give you a tab-separated file; if you want a comma-separated one, you could use the `"CSV"` format instead. See also [Importing and Exporting Data](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Would never have tried to use Chop.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to your question but the solution you get is not what you think it is: When you specify

```
Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
  "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.005}}
```

You are solving this a 2D spatial problem but you want to solve this as a 1D spatial and time dependent problem. The easiest way to do so is by using:

```
heatdist = 
 NDSolve[{HEATIMP == 0, BCTot, ic}, u, {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

And a plot:

[image]

If you want to refine the spatial resolution you can do so:

```
heatdist = 
 NDSolve[{HEATIMP == 0, BCTot, ic}, u, {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}}}}]
```

Have a look at the introductory [FEM tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html.en) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. That clears a few issues up.